# Char passing in C++ with pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Im having unclear image of pointers and char passing with functions. please anyone can tell me where im doing wrong and brief idea about pointers?ex : where should i use them, etc...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class book{
private:
    char *CName;
    int CFee;
    int NoPeople;
    int Income;
public:
    void setData(char &x,int y,int z){
        CName = &x;
        CFee = y;
        NoPeople = z;

    }
    void calIncome(){
        Income = CFee * NoPeople;

    }
    void viewIncome(){
        cout<<Income;
        cout<<CName;

    }
};
int main(){
    book b1;
    b1.setData('DISE',20000,30);
    b1.calIncome();
    b1.viewIncome();
}
```

im getting error in this code

//b1.setData('DISE',20000,30); "non-const lvalue reference to type 'char' cannot bind to a temparory of type 'int'"

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ answer is correct, anyway, since you are using C++ and not C, I would strongly recommend you to use the standard library containing the class sdt:string which simplifies working with chars totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `setData()` declaration to `void setData(const char *x,int y,int z)`

As you're currently doing you are expecting a reference to a single `char` as parameter, which cannot be used to assign a `char*` pointer that is meant to point at a character array.

Also you aren't specifying a character array literal in the call:

```
b1.setData('DISE',20000,30);
```

Needs to be changed to

```
b1.setData("DISE",20000,30);
        // ^    ^
```

Comment: Hi, i did this way. but im getting another error. see screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/5czedhrmzrdci0o/Screenshot%202014-03-24%2017.21.10.png

Comment: @ImBatman Sorry, to pass a character array **literal** you need to have a `const char*` pointer of course. Also note you'll need to provide an array allocation and copy from the parameter to keep t wth your class internal pointer then declaring that one `const` usually makes no sense. Fixed the answer ...

Answer (score 2):

In your code there is no need for pointers. You should use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
...
string CName
...
void setData(const string& x,int y,int z){
  CName = x;
```

and in `setData` call you should use double quotes (which are for strings) instead of single quotes (which are for individual characters).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. but im not getting the output. is this something to do with Xcode. here screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxeerxheryu7nr2/Screenshot%202014-03-24%2017.26.40.png

Comment: If your only intent is to store the string, pass it *by value* and move into the member.

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setData('DISE',20000,30);
```

char is only one char, like `'D'`, if you have multiple char, that is string, and you need to pass it as `"DISE"`

With your method signature, `void setData(char &x,int y,int z)` you can only pass char. That is one character.

Comment: Thanks.. i got the idea

Answer (score 0):

`setData` metod is completely useless here. Its work should be done by a constructor, and the `name` variable (which should NOT be named `CName` should be an `std::string`. `viewIncome` should automatically call `calIncome` and a dirty flag should probably be introduced. Otherwise `calIncome` should be a free/static function and the `income` member should be removed. The function parameters should also be reasonably captioned.

And I'll even answer the question:

```
class Book {
    std::string name;
    int fee;
    int noPeople;
    int income;

public:
    Book(std::string name, int fee, int noPeople) :
        name(std::move(name)),
        fee(fee),
        noPeople(noPeople)
    {
    }

    void calIncome() {
        income = fee * noPeople;
    }

    void viewIncome() {
        calIncome();
        std:: cout << income << name;
    }
};

int main() {
    Book b1 ("DISE", 20000, 30);
    b1.viewIncome();
}
```

See it live [**on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f131b78de1baa4c3).

Comment: Thank Bartek ..our lecturer always used char. never used string before. now i can think of using string as well(out of the box)thank you